# Combine two array and make a separate array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays namely a and b. I want to combine first value of a and first value of b as one array and that continues. (i.e)

```
a = ["05:25 PM", "3:05 PM"];
b = [60, 120];
```

Desired Output:

```
 ['05:25 PM', 60],
 ['3:05 PM', 120]
```

I have combined two array but it's not coming as expected

```js
a = ["05:25 PM", "3:05 PM"];
b = [60, 120];
    
const result = a.map((id, i) => ({ x: id, y: b[i] }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `{ x: id, y: b[i] }` represents an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this way instead to zip the arrays `a` and `b`:

```js
const a = ["05:25 PM", "3:05 PM"];
const b = [60, 120];

const c = a.map((item, index) => [item, b[index]]);
console.log(c);
```

The only difference between my code and yours is that mine produces arrays with two elements, one from `a` and one from `b`, instead of objects.